# Filtering folder files based on Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Directory Name);
//... Other code 
var allLines = info.GetFiles("*.dat")
                          .Where(p => p.CreationTime.Date ==DateTime.Today.Date)
                           .SelectMany(p => File.ReadAllLines(p.FullName));
```

I am trying to fetch files which have been created today . But with this code I am get all the .dat files present in the folder which are over 3 months old. Any help!! Newbie in C#

Comment: please provide more information. what is `info`?

Comment: DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Directory Name)

Comment: It might be an idea to do separation of concern so you can debug it a little better:
`var todayFiles = info.GetFiles("*.dat")
                          .Where(p => p.CreationTime.Date ==DateTime.Today.Date);`

And then:
`var allLines = todayFiles.SelectMany(p => File.ReadAllLines(p.FullName));`

Then you can check your collection `todayFiles` and confirm the `CreationTime` property is set correctly

Comment: The code looks OK. What do you see in Windows Explorer in the "Date created" column for the "over 3 months old" files?

Comment: if you have copied the files to a new directory this will reset the created date, so you may want to double check that the files you think are 3 months old actually are

Comment: @MikeT The file property shows modified , created , accessed date as old as 3 months . The code is taking all old files as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this

What I understood from the linq you provided is you want the files of type .dat whose creation date is today and do write operation.

```
   var allLines = info.GetFiles("*.dat")
                      .Where(p => p.CreationTime.Date > DateTime.Today.Date.AddMinutes(-1))
                       .SelectMany(p => File.ReadAllLines(p.FullName));
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why the `==` operator doesn't work, it seems odd that the `>` would work in this case and not the `==`

Comment: DateTime.Today.Date will return Date: {5/4/2016 12:00:00 AM}. See the time . In your case files were created after 12 am. that means you are putting == on date + time. So what I am doing is Minus 1 day then Date will be  {5/3/2016 12:00:00 AM} so files created today will be always greater than yesterday.

Comment: @Draken this technique is instead of using the CreationTime.Date to ignore the time component in this situation it should be useless

Comment: It's not my question @Siddu and they are using `p.CreationTime.Date ==DateTime.Today.Date` on both sides, so time should be irrevlevant in this matter as they would both be equal, only the date would differ

Comment: You can ignore the time component for this technique.

Comment: @Siddu you are right that created is date time but you have missed that he is calling the Date component which is the date with out time

Comment: @siddu This also gives same result . It is taking all the files . Not the files created today

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your:

```
.SelectMany(p => File.ReadAllLines(p.FullName));
```

is wrong.

Why you are not using just:

```
info.GetFiles("*.dat").Where(p => p.CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date).Select(p => p.FullName);
```

And you will get list of files

Comment: because he wants the content of the files not the name of the file

Comment: agreed, the code seems fine which suggests the problem is the directory, and files themselves

Comment: The file property shows date modified as old as 3 months old . And for files created today it is showing today's date & time in date modified property of file . The code is taking all the files

Comment: Try to Debug and see what dates are coming there

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine . Only thing was, I had to delete the previous compiled/debug file which did not involve date filtering . It was therefore taking the same even though clean solution & rebuild solution was done .